# Restkit integration into iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, xcode5

I have a problem during the import of Restkit Framework into my iOS project.
I followed this tutorial: [Intro to RestKit Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial)

I followed step by step the tutorial about Restkit integration but when I try to build I have always this error:

/myAPPDirectory/RestKit/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectMapping.h:23:9: 'RKValueTransformers.h' file not found

I have the same error also when I try to build a Restkit integrated example project.

I use Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Ray Wenderlich tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial for RestKit is not updated for the latest version. Use CocoaPods to install RestKit into your project. here is the [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods) and refer this tutorial from RestKit Wiki page [RestKit Tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)